# JSON get data using post-method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-post

I want to get a `JSON` file from another server `xyz.com` (not writhing here original site name for safety)  for my `HTML` page but the problem is that the website `xyz.com` only supports `HTTP POST` requests.
To check if my `HTML` code is working fine I use `HTTP GET` method and upload `JSON` data on another site that supports `HTTP GET` request. And I found that it is working fine. But when I try for `HTTP POST` method it is not working. Can you help me?

I am using currently and working fine

```
<script>

   $(function() {


  var people = [];

  $.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/c307c',function(data) {
      $.each(data.video, function(i, f) {
```

HTML CODE FOR `xyz.com` and it also return a `.json`  file

```
<html>

<head>


<form action="https://www.xyz.php" method="POST" >
<div class="container" style="width:100%;">
<center></center>
</div>
  <div class="container" style="width:100%;">
    <label for="userId"><b>UserId</b></label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Your User Id" name="userId" autofocus required>

    <label for="Passkey"><b>Passkey</b></label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Passkey" name="Passkey" required>
        
    <button type="submit" >GET Json File From Server</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is i tried but not working

```
<script>

   $(function() {


  var people = [];

  $.post('https://xyz.php', usedId=5&passkey=55, function(data) {
      $.each(data.video, function(i, f) {
```

Comment: This sounds like a backend problem. Your server needs to respond to the post request by serving the file back to you.

Comment: no when i request in html it working but not working in java script.because i am not able to deliver usedid and passkey data successfully

Comment: Please see this page for a jQuery example on how to `POST` a form using `Ajax` and put results in a `div` https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ That Should clear things up on how to use `$.post()`

Comment: @KUMAR: It looks like you are posting directly from the form to the PHP file. The name of the Passkey attribute is capitalized in the form, so, its submitting ```userId=5&Passkey=55```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way code

```
$.post( "https://xyz.php", { usedId: 5, passkey: 55},
function(data) {
        //your code
 } );
```

Comment: you are missing curly brackets `}` after `passkey: 55`

Comment: when i inspect element then it is not requesting for a post request

Comment: you want to call xyz.php when form submitted am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Some changes I suggest:

- Give the form an ID, in this case `login` seems like an appropriate ID
- Standardize your capitalization for form fields

Here's some code to get you started. You'll notice I'm creating your `data` twice. Decide if you want to build your data by hand or use jQuery's serialization to do it for you. Since this is a simple form, the latter is probably fine.

I'm also getting the AJAX endpoint right from the form so you aren't repeating yourself there.

```
// when the document has loaded...
$(document).ready(function () {
    // if the user is already logging in
    var login = false;

    // when the form is submitted...
    $('#login').on('submit', function (event) {
        // block the form if it's already been submitted
        if (login) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();
            return;
        }

        // lock the form
        login = true;

        // get a handle on the form
        // I use $ as a prefix to differentiate jQuery objects
        // currentTarget is the subject of the event
        var $form = $(event.currentTarget);

        var url = $form.prop('action');

        /*
         * MANUAL
         */
        // form fields are added to the form object as properties by name attribute
        // note that they are not jQuery objects
        var data = {
            userId: $form.userId.value,
            passKey: $form.passKey.value
        };

        /*
         * AUTOMATIC
         */
        // uses jQuery's form serialization to automatically create an object mapping names to values
        var data = $form.serialize();

        $.post(url, data)
            // on success
            .done(function (data, status, request) {
                $.each(data.video, function (i, f) {
                    var link = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+ f.video;

                    // backslash at the end of a string means to continue the string on the next line
                    var $row = $('<tr>\
                        <td>' + f.videoName + '</td>\
                        <td>' + f.date + '</td>\
                        <td>' + f.time + '</td>\
                        <td>' + f.liveStatus + '</td>\
                        <td><a target="_blank" href="' + link + '">' + link + '</a></td>\
                    </tr>');

                    $row.appendTo('#userdata tbody');
            })
            // on failure
            .fail(function (request, status, error) {
                window.alert('Failed with a status of ' + status + ': ' + error);
            })
            // executes after either of the above
            // parameters are inconsistent and use either done's or fail's
            .always(function () {
                // do cleanup, i.e. unlock form submission, close modal dialogs, etc.
                login = false
            });

        // stop default form submission
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: when i inspect element then it is not requesting for a post request

Comment: I've modified it to show you how to add it to the form.

Comment: i am sending you full code please make it one click exutable

Comment: Use the above code as the entire contents inside your `script` element.

Comment: but bro i have a lot of operation after i get a json file

Comment: bro i posted a answer please correct it as you want. I am new in programming

Comment: Alright, I've updated my answer for you. Please take notes and read my comments.

Comment: bro when i click on get data button it open json file from server not showing in table

Comment: Can you post the response you get from the server? Do `console.log(data)` in the `done` handler.

Comment: i get a json file that was because html  form action

Comment: Bro Please edit my full code and paste full code thanks bro

Comment: Trust me, this is doing you a favor in the long run. Your code is not maintainable and will break. Paste the response content.

Answer (score 0):

Please make necessery change so that when i click on button it take data from server and show in a table format

```
<html>
<head>

<form action="https://xyz.php" method="POST" >
<div class="container" style="width:100%;">
<center></center>
</div>
  <div class="container" style="width:100%;">
    <label for="userId"><b>UserId</b></label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Your User Id" name="userId" autofocus required>

    <label for="passKey"><b>Passkey</b></label>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Passkey" name="passKey" required>

    <button type="submit" >GET DATA</button>
  </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>

<script>

   $(function() {


  var people = [];

 $.post( "xyz.php",function(data) {
      $.each(data.video, function(i, f) {

        var link = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+ f.video;       
         var tblRows = "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + f.videoName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.date + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.time + "</td>"  +
          "<td>" + f.videoDuration + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.liveStatus + "</td>" + "<td><a target='_blank' href='"+link+"'>"+link+"</a></td>" + "</tr>";
          $(tblRows).appendTo("#userdata tbody");

    });

  });

});
</script>

</head>


<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="profile">
   <table id= "userdata" width="50%" border="2">
  <thead>
            <th>VIDEO NAME</th>
            <th>DATE</th>
            <th>TIME</th>           
            <th>DURACTION</th>
            <th>LIVE STATUS</th>
            <th>LINK</th>
        </thead>
      <tbody>

       </tbody>
   </table>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```